# How to set proxy settings on MacOS using python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, proxy

How to change the internet proxy settings using python in MacOS to set `Proxy server` and `Proxy port`

I do that with windows using this code:

```
import _winreg as winreg

INTERNET_SETTINGS = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings', 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)

def set_key(name, value):
    _, reg_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name)
    winreg.SetValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name, 0, reg_type, value)

set_key('ProxyEnable', 0)
set_key('ProxyOverride', u'*.local;<local>')  # Bypass the proxy for localhost
set_key('ProxyServer', u'proxy.example.com:8080')
```

is this possible to do it on MacOS ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a long time of search, I found this way of how to change proxy on MacOs using python.

We need to use `networksetup` via terminal.

To set HTTP proxy server on MacOS using python:

```
import os

proxy = "proxy.example.com"
port = 8080

def Proxy_on():
    os.system('networksetup -setwebproxy Ethernet '+proxy+' '+port)

Proxy_on()
```

and to turn it off:

```
import os

proxy = "proxy.example.com"
port = 8080

def Proxy_off():
    os.system('networksetup -setwebproxystate Ethernet off')

Proxy_off()
```

If the network service isn't named just **"Ethernet"**, you may need to parse `networksetup -listallnetworkservices` or `-listnetworkserviceorder` to get the correct name.