# How to implement Mac OS HTTP monitor

Tags: macos, http

I need write application that monitoring all http requests/responces on mac os. How to register proxy server in Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

I found simple example - python tcp server that redirect requests/responses and code that automation set Mac OS proxies settings.

Python script was taken from http://www.cppfun.com/python-2-7-simple-http-proxy-server.htm, Mac OS proxies settings configurator from [How to set proxy settings on MacOS using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904647/how-to-set-proxy-settings-on-macos-using-python)

```
import socket, sys
import os
from thread import *

max_conn = 8
buffer_size = 8192


def proxy_on(port):
    os.system('networksetup -setwebproxy Ethernet '+'127.0.0.1'+' '+str(port))

def proxy_off():
    os.system('networksetup -setwebproxystate Ethernet off')

def app():
    try:
        listen_port = int(raw_input("[*] Enter listening port(a number eg 8098):"))
        proxy_on(listen_port)
        start(listen_port)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print  "\n[*] User requested interrupt\n[*] Program exiting ..."
        sys.exit()

def start(listen_port):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind(('', listen_port))
        s.listen(max_conn)
        print "[*] Init sockets ... Done"
        print "[*] Sockets bind success ..."
        print "[*] Proxy server success [%d]\n" % listen_port
    except Exception, e:
        print "\n", e
        print "[*] Unable to init socket, maybe try another port"
        sys.exit(2)

    while True:
        try:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            data = conn.recv(buffer_size)
            start_new_thread(conn_str, (conn, data, addr))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            s.close()
            print "\n[*] Proxy server shutdown ..."
            print "[*] Have a good day !"
            proxy_off()
            sys.exit(1)
    s.close()

def conn_str(conn, data, addr):
    try:
        first_line = str(data).split('\n')[0]
        url = first_line.split(' ')[1]
        print url
        host, port = get_host_and_port(url)
        print host, port, data
        proxy_server(host, port, conn, addr, data)
    except Exception, e:
        print "\n", e
        print "[*] Get the http url or port fail ..."
        sys.exit(1)

def get_host_and_port(url):
    import urllib
    _, rest = urllib.splittype(url)
    host, rest = urllib.splithost(rest)
    host, port = urllib.splitport(host)
    if port is None:
        port = 80

    return host,port

def proxy_server(host, port, conn, addr, data):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.send(data)

        while True:
            reply = s.recv(buffer_size)
            if len(reply) > 0:
                conn.send(reply)
                dat = float(len(reply))/1024.0
                dat = "%.3s KB" % str(dat)
                print "[*] Request done : %s => %s <=" % (addr[0], dat)
            else:
                break
        s.close()
        conn.close()
    except socket.error, (value, message):
        print "\n[*] Socket error %d:%s" % (value, message)
        s.close()
        conn.close()
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # power by cppfun.com
    app()
# also you can change it yourself
```